# In massive gravity, does emission of gravitons imply loss of mass?

Tags: gravity

If I interact gravitationally with another object, then the theory of massive gravity implies that I am exchanging massive gravitons with that other object.  Am I the source of these gravitons?  If so, does that mean that, in this theory, gravitational interaction requires a constant exchange of energy?  If so, do I lose (probably very small) mass just be being in a gravitational field?  If not, why not?